# Aligning a single item to the right of a navbar

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a header component with a

tag and navbar inside of it. I want the navbar collapsible button on the left and the

tag on the far right. What would be the best way of accomplishing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.header {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <div class="logo">
    <p>N</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
  <div class="bg-dark p-4">
    <h5 class="text-white h4">Collapsed content</h5>
    <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-transparent">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please include the version of BS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example with the tag on the right and the icon on the left. I hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="First navbar example">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExample01" aria-controls="navbarsExample01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Never expand</a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```